# i want make a call from my local machine to mobile phone via dotnet core and ATAPI library

Tags: c#, .net, telephony, tapi

i want create a app to call to mobile phone via local fax modem
i used ATAPI library from nuget package X64 version
this is link to nuget : [ATAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ATAPI.X64/)
and this is my Code :

```
        TapiManager manager = new TapiManager("telephone");
        manager.Initialize();
        TapiProvider tapiProvider = manager.Providers[2];
        manager.NewCall += Manager_NewCall;
        TapiLine line = manager.Lines[manager.Lines.Length - 1];
        
        line.Open(MediaModes.DataModem);
        ITapiCall call = line.MakeCall("MYMOBILENUMBER");
```

destination mobile number was ring but application throw exception

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

how i fix that or help to me i can do that with any library or any method that work easy

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atapi Only work On Classic .net ...
i Switch my project to .net 4.8 and Worked ...

another library that i can use is [TapiEX](http://www.tapiex.com/samples.htm)